# Upload an XML file to a remote site with XHR

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload an xml file to an external URL that will process the file and give feedback on any missing or incorrect information with that XML file.  The feedback needs to be in XML format.  I am trying to use XHR to do this.  It seems I can make the call but the IT people at the remote site say they are not receiving the XML document.   The remote site does send feedback with an error.  Will someone take a look at my code to see if I have missed something?  It is almost like there is a missing link between my form and the actual upload process.  Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

var file = input.files[];


var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'External URL', false);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                        if((xmlHttp.readyState==4)&&(xmlHttp.status == 200))
                        {
                                xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
 txt="";
 x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Records");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
   txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
   }
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
                        }
                }
xhr.send(fd);
</script>

<form action="External URL" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="Post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>
```

Comment: SOP violation? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: What is the error?  Surely you are seeing something in your javascript console.

Comment: Also, this will never work in IE9 or earlier due to lack of File API support.  Finally, `input.files[]` is not a valid statement.  Did you mean `input.files[0]`?

Comment: I think by using the FormData() it gets passed the SOP.  There error says Invalid User Parameters.  The remote IT said this is because they are not seeing the xml.  Yes, Sorry, i did mean input.files[0].

Comment: @user2332749 You need to deal with cross-domain requests appropriately server-side.  Read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more details.  Also, I have no idea what XML you are referring to.  You are not sending any XML, just a multipart encoded request with one multipart boundary that contains your file.

Comment: What do i need to do to correct this?  I am trying to post an xml file.

Comment: There is no XML file anywhere in your example.  If you are trying to send XML, simply do so via XHR/ajax.

Comment: The xml file is being generated elsewhere.  The form has a browse button to search for the file.  Do you have an example of what it should look like?  Thank you.  If you know a better way to do this please let me know as I am really new at this.

Comment: Oh, I see, the file you are appending to the FormData object is an XML file?  If this is true, mentioning the file type was a bit confusing for me as it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Correct.  I am sorry for the confusion.